# Why can't ubuntu recognize my mobile broadband usb dongle when I plug it into the usb 3.0 port?

Tags: 12.04, networking, usb, mobile-broadband

I have a Mobile Broadband USB dongle. When I plug it into the usb 2.0 port ubuntu recognizes it and connects quickly, but on a usb 3.0 port ubuntu does not recognize it at all! This problem is NOT unique, and I have experienced it with many brands of dongles and laptops. (but all on ubuntu 12.04). Please help.

Comment: You can include result of `lsusb` in both case. Probably you are facing same issue as [Ubuntu 12.04 - USB3 issue with mobile broadband usb sticks](http://askubuntu.com/q/163139). Also do a `dmesg -c`, plug it on usb2.0, once recognized then execute & post result of `dmesg` here. Again unplug, clear dmesg (`dmesg -c`), replug. Post the output of `dmesg` again. Don't post the result as comment. You can edit your question using `edit`